# Windows 2000, IE6, applet attaches to wrong frame

Tags: applet, internet-explorer-6, windows-nt

I have an applet which communicates with the browser via javascript. I load the applet, and some javascript, in an iframe, and in Windows 2000 with IE6, I have determined that the messages the applet propagates hit the parent frame, rather than the iframe.

Is there a better solution to fix this than include windows2k.hacks.js, with proxy methods for each method the applet calls? Someone please tell me there's a simpler solution than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be using [jActivating](http://jactivating.sourceforge.net/en/). This library does not work with IE6 and Win2k for some reason, so just scan the useragent and guard against this specific configuration.

Comment: @Stefan: I've contacted the developer directly about the issue, although if someone else wants to officially log a bug, they may.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the messages back to the frame?

Generally its

```
JSObject myWin = JSObject.getWindow(this);
myWin.call("JsFunction", "My Message");
```

Comment: That's how I do it, yet it fails. I created a basic implementation of my site without rich content, and then the same applet loading in the iframe attached to the iframe correctly, so the applet cannot possibly be the issue.

I'm more stumped than ever, now, however.